# Using Varchar column of a table to search text column in another table

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to find all my business Id's that are not part of an approved company Information XML.

My business ID exists on my business table as a `varchar(255)` data type
My companyxml exists on my companyinfo table as a `text` data type

```
SELECT [bus_id] FROM [dbo].[tbl_businesses]
WHERE [bus_id] NOT IN (SELECT cmp_companyXML FROM tbl_companyinfo WHERE 
    cmp_approved = 'Approved')
```

I am getting this error

> Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.

Since I don't have any similar data in either table I have to use a subquery. I  am also doing a `NOT IN` so I have to evaluate each business and then evaluate all of my company xmls that are approved, and select it only if its not there.

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but if you have XML data, why are you not using the XML datatype?

Comment: `NOT IN` is dangerous if  `cmp_companyXML` is nullable column.

Answer (score 1):

Use `CAST` to cast the column as varchar(max) for a valid SQL comparison.

```
select [bus_id] from [dbo].[tbl_businesses]
where [bus_id] not in 
(select cast(cmp_companyXML as varchar(max)) 
from tbl_companyinfo 
where cmp_approved = 'Approved')
```

Comment: that works, but it looks like my results are now not working haha, it returns to me all records i have

Comment: Are you sure you don't need `CONTAINS` instead of `IN`?

Answer (score 1):

It is because the text datatype is not compatible. Look at this article. It may be usefull to you: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/12/04/sql-server-fix-error-402-the-data-types-ntext-and-varchar-are-incompatible-in-the-equal-to-operator/

You may use the convert command in your subquery:

```
 select  CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), cmp_companyXML)...
```